# Click unable to register group command

Tags: python, bash, python-click

I am trying to run a click cli through a bash with a different command groups run through a single command collection.

`src/preprocessing_extract_data/scripts/main.py`

```
import click 

@click.group()
def run_preprocessing_extract_data():
    pass


@run_preprocessing_extract_data.command()
@click.option(
    "--start_date",
    type=click.DateTime(formats=["%Y-%m-%d"]),
    required=True,
    help="Start date for the pipeline",
)
@click.option(
    "--end_date",
    type=click.DateTime(formats=["%Y-%m-%d"]),
    required=True,
    help="End date for the pipeline",
)
def main(start_date, end_date):
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`src/scripts/main.py`

```
from click import CommandCollection

from src.preprocessing_extract_data.scripts.main import run_preprocessing_extract_data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cmds = [
        run_preprocessing_extract_data,
        # a few more similar command groups
    ]
    cli = CommandCollection(sources=cmds)
    cli()
```

`scripts/entrypoint.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
start_date="$1"
end_date="$2"

python src/scripts/main.py run_preprocessing_extract_data --start_date=$start_date --end_date=$end_date
```

I run it using `./scripts/entrypoint.sh --start_date="2020-11-01" --end_date="2021-12-01" --today="2021-12-10"` but it keeps failing and throws the following error:

```
Usage: main.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
Try 'main.py --help' for help.

Error: No such command 'run_preprocessing_extract_data'.
```

Comment: `run_preprocessing_extract_data` the group, but `main` the name of the command, so you should invoke that script with `main` as an argument.

Comment: Could you add an answer? It's still not that clear to me @a_guest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/commands/#merging-multi-commands):

> The default implementation for such a merging system is the `CommandCollection` class. It accepts a list of other multi commands and makes the commands available on the same level.

Hence, your script now has a command `main`; you can check this by running your script with `--help` (or no arguments at all): `python src/scripts/main.py --help`.

Hence you can do the following:

```sh
python src/scripts/main.py main --start_date="$start_date" --end_date="$end_date"
```

By the way, invoking your shell script should be done without the `--start_date`: `./scripts/entrypoint.sh "2020-11-01" "2021-12-01"`.

Comment: Ok I tried it with `main` and it works. But when I change the command name to `main_preprocessing_extract_data` it suddenly doesn't work. I have multiple commands that I need to run and currently all of them have the same name `main`, so I need a way to distinguish them.

Comment: Ok I figured it out, I need to convert the underscores to dashes like so`main-preprocessing-extract-data`, that fixed it. But now another issue, some of the commands need another arg `today` which is also passed in through the bash script and now it says that the `main.py main-preprocessing-extract-data` does not take it.

Comment: @yudhiesh So then just don't pass it as an argument.